# FireFox add-on develepment using react Cross Origin issues

Tags: reactjs, firefox, cors

So for this firefox add-on, I wanted to implement an auto-login function(i.e. login at popup). At first it did work on the web, but when I load the extension to the firefox it gives me a Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:[backend]/auto-login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'moz-extension://login-extension@example.com'). I think the reason why is because I use origins parameter in the backend code with origins directed to the frontend server but can't figure out how to fix

backend:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:[frontend]",
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: [
      "set-cookie",
      "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
    ],
  }));

app.options('*', cors());

app.get('/auto-login', async (req, res) => {
    const authToken = req.cookies.authToken;

    if (!authToken) {
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }

    //const authToken = cookie['authToken']

    try {
        const decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(authToken, "DUMMYKEY");
        //const { username, password } = decoded;
        const user = await getUserByUsername(decoded.username);
        const { username, fullname, email } = user;
        

        console.log("User ID:", username);
        //console.log("User Password:", password);
    
        return res.json({user: { username, fullname, email }, status: "success", message: "Login successful!"});
      } catch (error) {
        // If there's an error decoding the JWT, it might be expired or tampered with
        console.error("Error decoding authToken:", error);
        return res.sendStatus(401);
      }
});
```

frontend:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    async function autoLogin() {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:[backend]/auto-login", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === "success") {
        setIsSubmitted(true);
        sessionStorage.setItem("user_id", JSON.stringify(data.user));
        setLoginUser(data.user);
        // Redirect to Logon page after successful login
        console.log(username);
        //getUser();
        navigate("/Logon");
      } else {
        navigate("/");
      }
    }
    
      autoLogin();
    
  }, []);
```